# Workflow execution

Tags: c#

I am currently building piece of code which waits for an external event to happen in a some interval, (Let us say if AccountOpened). I need to check if account not opened in particular days sends a followup , then check for certain days to wait for the the if follow up does not then send a followup again or execute a different workflow altogether.

Here what I am thinking of build

- Store the current state along with the rules , and poll the database
  of external event and trigger logic.
- Use some kind of workflow engine and hands all the responsibility to that piece.

Any suggestion would be helpful?

Comment: A workflow engine is going to use a poll or database trigger or something of that sort anyway so why not roll your own. I would poll with a System.Timers.Timer every minute or whatever resolution is acceptable because it is simple, a loop is too hungry, and a db trigger is a bit of work.

Comment: @strongbutgood: Thanks , But any kind of pattern I can use to simplify this whole coding